# Azure Event Grid Costing if event are batched

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

If we choose to batch 100 events in one batch. Event grid delivers 100 events in as single batch. I will be billed  **$0.000060 for one operation** or **number of events sent  $0.000060 x 100**?

Pricing document talks about only operations. So, if I have 100 events in batch size of 64 Kb it will cost  $0.000060. Am I right?

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/event-grid/

Edit: updated cost for one operation.

Comment: You're still going to be billed for 64KB chunks.

Comment: @SeanFeldman could you provide some proof, please?

Comment: It's documented and public: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/event-grid/event-schema as well as https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/event-grid/. I didn't bother putting it as an answer as it's so trivial. No proof is needed 

Comment: I understand the batch size.
Question is,
10 event of 5 KB = 10 Operations
If batching enabled
(10 events of 5 Kb batched into 1 operation) = 1 operation
So, according to documentation. Both going to cost same or different.

Comment: @Anoop Are you asking about the charging of *the batch delivery operation* to the http event handler endpoint (such as in the current version only for webhook and Azure Function)?  Note, that the batched event delivery feature will take advantage only for **high-throughput scenarios**, see more details  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry#batched-event-delivery. In this case, each batched event delivery (<=64kB) is one operation as a subject of the charging. Note, that the first 100k operations are free.

Comment: @RomanKiss , Thanks, this is exactly I wanted to confirm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The pricing is clear for event grid:

- First 100,000 operations are free
- Price per million operations is $0.60
- Events are charged per 64 KB unit of data. Events larger than 64 KB are charged in multiples of 64 KB. For example, a single event of 96 KB will be billed as two separate 64 KB events.

Microsoft does not make any difference whether events are batched or not. All your events will count against your free tier in your case (since you are way below the 100,000 operations).